# Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Acabo de instalar Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1.0) en mi pc con windows 10.
El problema es que no puedo crear una conexión desde el Oracle SQL Developer y aparece el mensaje en rojo (ver imágen).

[image: Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection]

Al probar la conectividad desde el símbolo del sistema sale el siguiente error ORA-12541: TNS:No hay ningun listener.

```
C:\Users\JEAN>tnsping ONE

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 16-SEP-2017 00:11:30
Copyright (c) 1997, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Archivos de parßmetros utilizados:
D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Adaptador TNSNAMES utilizado para resolver el alias
Intentando contactar con (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = ONE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no hay ning·n listener
```

Y así es como tengo el tnsnames.ora y el listener.ora

tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ONE =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ONE)
    )   )

LISTENER_ONE =   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )   )
```

listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = Oracle8)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.38)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\JEAN\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\log
```

¿Qué debo hacer para resolverlo?

Comment: en lugar de **xe** prueba poniendo **orcl**

Comment: tambien lo intenté pero me da el mismo mensaje

Comment: estoy con el mismo problema, como hiciste para desinstalarlo? no me aparece en la lista de programas para desinstalar en el panel de control. Gracias!

Comment: Me pasa lo mismo... alguien tiene otra solución? :)

Comment: Revisa la URL de conexión, puede estar errada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que hice finalmente fué desinstalar el oracle, luego en la instalación no cambie el nombre de la instancia (lo deje el **orcl**) en la instalación anterior lo cambie por ONE por que me gustaba ese nombre aun asi me daba error, al finalizar la instalación abri el sql developer,en el campo SID puse orcl y la conexión se realizó con exito.